# Rails 2.3 App problems running database migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have an old legacy app that I need to add some new tables to. I recently ran rake db:migrate to make the changes and go the following error:

> PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "schema_migrations" already exists :
>   CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varying(255) NOT
>   NULL)

I looked in my schema.rb file and found for the "version" character and found it:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20170415055458) do .. end
```

but I don't understand why this is causing the error. I have not made any changes and can't figure this  out. Any assistance appreciated.

I have tried dropping the database and rebuilding it but I get errors about relations not existing when they do and the schema.rb file is blank. It's like it does not know there are tables in the database.

Comment: Use `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` comment

Comment: Hi Then I would lose all of the data in my database

Comment: get seed dump and reset ur db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://gist.github.com/TylerRick/9811465 and https://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/6051, it could be that the `schema_migrations` table is part of the public postgresql schema, while the `database.yml` doesn't specify it. See if you already have a value for `schema_search_path` and if adding `public` to it helps.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: project_development
  schema_search_path: public
```

or

```
  schema_search_path: "existing,public"
```

More about `schema_search_path`: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/5aa2892b43-set-schema-search-path

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: This works for my local  development database but for some reason not my production on heroku. any ideas

Comment: Great, what did you do exactly? you would need to do the same for `production:`

Comment: I did, I added the same line to the db.yml but for some reason when I did rake db:migrate I get the same error where it tries to create the schema_migrations table. Basically, when it tries to look at the db to find the tables it does not find the tables for some reason.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it solves my problem on my local machine. I have asked Heroku support to find out why it does not work on their system. Thanks again Stéphane.

Comment: Nothing yet. They are requesting more details. I'll report any findings

Answer (score 0):

You can not and do not need to create table schema_migrations. Rails auto create this table for keeping the migration version. Please check your migration files and remove command to create schema_migrations table.

Comment: I'm not trying to recreate the schema_migrations table. I'm just trying to run a migration to add a column to one of the tables. This error is produced when I do so.